# Nancy Self Host blank response with Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

## Resolved in Nancy 0.6

---

I'm trying to get self-hosted Nancy to return a razor view and I can't get it to work.  The sample in the Nancy source code uses a web project, but the [page they have](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine) doesn't say this is required.  I've tried specifying the config sections but again they say "*This step is totally optional*" (italics are theirs).  Tracing through the source it doesn't look like razor is a valid view engine, but I don't see where I can add it either in the config or in my own NancyModule...  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: View Engines]

When I finally figured out they were looking in the views folder, it seems that the cshtml is a supported extension, but the DefaultViewFactory doesn't have it associated with a view engine so I get null:

[image]

My code:

```
public Module1()
{
    Get["/me"] = parms =>
    {
        return View["Static.html"]; // WORKS!
    };
    Get["/you"] = parms =>
    {
        dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
        //return View["~/Static.cshtml", model];
        //return View["/Static.cshtml", model];
        return View["Static.cshtml", model]; // blank page, no error or anything
    };
}
```

Static.cshtml is just an html page that says "Hello, world!"

Comment: I hate to ask but did you add a reference to `Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll`? Out of the box there is nothing special you need to do. The paths aren't necessarily required to be in the `Views` folder either as you can specify paths relative to root.

Comment: Yep, but Nancy scanned assemblies for view engines prior to that assembly being loaded into my AppDomain and never updated its list.  Forcing the assembly to load prior to using Nancy fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Just out of curiosity, what type of project are you using since it sounds like you weren't using a web project.

Comment: Self hosted, actually a WPF app

Comment: Yet another legitimate, useful question closed on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10):

console,form and wpf projects locate view files at same location as executable file. it means you must copy your view.cshtml files to your projects bin\debug folder to work on debug mode.
So: mark your .cshtml files as copy to output

Comment: That's what worked for me. Too bad this question was closed.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out one part of my problem, the razor assembly wasn't loaded into my AppDomain when I created my NancyHost.  NancyHost has TinyIoc scan and create a list of all classes in all loaded assemblies when it starts, and this list never gets udpated.  I fixed it by creating a RazorViewEngine to force the assembly to load.  Using the Register() call works also, but I think only because it forces the assembly to load, I think Nancy has their own container. All of these locations works, but it still does not work if I put it in my NancyModule:

```
//TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<RazorViewEngine>(); // WORKS
//RazorViewEngine rve = new RazorViewEngine(); // WORKS
m_Host = new NancyHost(m_Uri);
//TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<RazorViewEngine>(); // WORKS
m_Host.Start();
TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<RazorViewEngine>(); // WORKS
```

If someone wants to re-write this answer and figure out a cleaner way or a better solution, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Is this the issue caused by you using an ancient version of Nancy? If so, can you update the question/answer please? :-)

Comment: I had the exact same problem using Nancy 0.9 release. If I created an instance of the RazorViewEngine before the host it all worked fine.

Comment: This issue happens when you are using Nancy.Hosted.Self and in Testing Projects.  Explicitly Registering the `RazorViewEngine` in the application startup process or in the TestObject's ctor resolve the problem. (This is true still in Nancy 0.16.1)

Answer (score 1):

I had a sort of similar  problem with nancy 0.8.0 and Razor. I had Nancy, Host.Self and ViewEngine.Razor downloaded and installed, and referenced.

Still when compiling the compiler could not find the Razor namespace in Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor (event though the object browser and Reflector showed that the namespace and the types perfectly well), I did all the normal namespace reference vodo; clean, remove, add, pm unstall, pm install, manually moved the dlls to the bin, put on my lucky compiling hat, spat three times over my left shoulder etcetera but still got the same result. No Razor loaded into the AppDomain...

I reverted to manually loading the assembly into the appdomain and use activator to create a instance of the RazorViewEngine type for the Tiny.IoC Container factory.

The actual problem was that the startup project of my solution was targeted to the .NET Framework 4 client Profile. Apparently the client .Net bundle is unable to consume and view some parts for a dll compiled for the full 4 version.

Anyways. Changed my build to "normal" .NET 4 and everything is back to normal. The compiler finds the types in the namespace and Tiny.IoC is able to hook everything up.